# How do I find this relation between total energy and fermi energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, fermions, fermi-energy

I am currently studying the Sommerfeld model. I understand how to find the fermi energy $\epsilon_F$ by using the density of states function but I am unsure how to answer this question about the total energy. I am asked to show that the total energy of a collection of $N$ free fermions in 3D is $U_0 = \frac{3}{5}N\epsilon_F$ assuming $T\rightarrow0$. I know this must be done through integrating energy per state in state space but I don't know where the fermi energy comes into play.

I am then asked to derive how the pressure $P=-\dfrac{\text{d}U_0}{\text{d}V}$ relates to the volume, to compare this to the classical ideal gas model and to explain what balances this pressure in solids and in neutron stars. I understand that a pressure arising from the pauli exclusion principle is compensated for by gravity in a Neutron star, but I am unsure how this works in everyday solids. My first guess here is a simple coulomb attraction from the nuclei.

Comment: At T=0 what is special about the Fermi energy?

Comment: It is the largest available energy value a particle can have.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Now, how would that end up in an expression for the total energy?

Comment: So I am thinking now that I must integrate the density of states function from 0 to the fermi energy giving me $\frac{1}{6}\pi (\dfrac{2mL^2\epsilon_F}{\pi^2h^2})^{3/2}$ but this says energy is proportional to fermi energy to the power  of 3/2

Comment: The integral of the density of states tells you the total number of states. What tells you the total energy?

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious here, but I assumed that integrating energy per state over the positive $n$ quadrant of 3D $n$-space from 0 to the maximum distance from 0 - the fermi energy would give me total energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$U_0 = \left(\int_0^{E_F} E \ f(E) \  D(E) \ \text dE \right) \propto E^{5/2} \\ N=\left(\int_0^{E_F} f(E) \  D(E) \ \text dE \right) \propto E^{3/2} $$

You can work out the integrals (it is tricky without approximations) to see $\dfrac{U_0}{N}=\dfrac{3}{5}E_F$.

For pressure:  $P = -\left(\dfrac{\partial U_0}{\partial V}\right)_N$

From your comments $E_F \propto \left(\dfrac{N}{V}\right)^{2/3}$. It should be fairly simple to work it out from here. You can now compare this with the classical version. I suggest you refer to standard textbooks like *Solid State Physics* by Ashcroft and Mermin or *Introduction to Solid State Physics* by C. Kittel for a better understanding.